# unable to send emails using google Smtp client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, smtpclient

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application inside my visual studio . no my web application is basically a web site for public users (so i am not using https). now my web site provides a normal contact us form , and the following Post Contact action method :-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(Contact c)
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage();

            // Set the to and from addresses.
            // The from address must be your GMail account
            mail.From = new MailAddress("****@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("****@yahoo.com"));

            // Define the message
            mail.Subject = "New Feedback from Web Site";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
            //System.Environment.NewLine
            mail.Body = "Dear Sirs," + System.Environment.NewLine +
                "New Feedback has been submitted fromWeb site, with the following details :- " + System.Environment.NewLine +
                "Name :- " + c.Name + System.Environment.NewLine +
                "Email :- " + c.Email +
                "Telephone :- " + c.Telephone + System.Environment.NewLine
                +
                "Message :- " + c.Message


                ;

            // Create a new Smpt Client using Google's servers
            var mailclient = new SmtpClient();
            mailclient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            mailclient.Port = 587;

            // This is the critical part, you must enable SSL
            mailclient.EnableSsl = true;

            // Specify your authentication details
            mailclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
                                             "***@gmail.com",
                                             "***");

            mailclient.Send(mail);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{Your Feedback has been submitted. Thanks");
            return RedirectToAction("Contact");

        }
```

but this will raise the following exception:-

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
```

so i have the following question :-

- what is causing the error ?
- should i use https inside my contact page to be able to send email from my application ?

Comment: How about changing the port number to 465(SSL) instead of 587(TLS)?

Comment: @HwasooLee ok i change it to 465 now i am getting this error "Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."

Comment: @HwasooLee when i use 465 i got a time out exception . i use the following code "SmtpClient mailclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
mailclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***@gmail.com", "****");
mailclient.EnableSsl = true;" but i got this exception:-


An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The operation has timed out.

Answer (score 1):

try to add Credentials property,

```
SmtpClient mailclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
mailclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. now i tried the following SmtpClient mailclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
mailclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***@gmail.com", "****");
mailclient.EnableSsl = true;


but i got the following exception "An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The operation has timed out."

Comment: i checked my gmail and seems there is a message send to my Inbox that gmail prevented an attempt to login to my account, i say that this was me , and i try to send the contact form again but i received the same exception... not sure what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set your gmail account to allow less secure apps (enable Basic Authentication).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2984937